# Is there any function for calculating k and b coefficients for linear regression model with only one independent variable?

Tags: python, linear-regression, least-squares

I know I can just write needed method by myself but there must be a function for this because this problem is so common as heck. If somebody does't understand what I am talking about take a look at the following formula
[{Image must be here}](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I9oaF.png)

For example, I have a function y = kx+b where y is dependent variable, and x is independent. I need to calculate k (slope) and b (intercept), and I have formulas from the picture, and everything those formulas need. Is there any function in common data science libraries which can help calculate those ones? I mentioned "only one independent variable" because sometimes there are multiple independent vars which leads to multidimentional plots

Googling gives nothing. I already use my own implementation of those ones, but I prefer native functions from packages such as scipy and numpy, or sklearn

Answer (score 2, accepted):

not sure to fully understand the question (especially, what do you mean by "one independent variable"?), so I try to reformulate. If you have two variables, `x` and`y`, both represented by samples `(x_1,..., x_n), (y_1,..., y_n)` and that you suspect a linear relationship between them, `y = a*x +b`, then you can use [`numpy.polyfit`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.polyfit.html) to find the coefficients `a` and `b`. Here is an example:

```
import numpy as np

n = 100
x = np.linspace(0, 1, n)
y = 2*x + 0.3

a, b = np.polyfit(x, y, 1)
print(f"a={a}, b={b}")
```

Returns

```
a=2.0, b=0.30000000000000016
```

Hope that helps!